# How to use Dzen instead of Xmobar in this unusual setup

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I am a Haskell newbie and I currently don't have time to really learn Haskell so I'm asking for help from the experts that have it already figured out. :)

This is my current xmonad.hs file: https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/dd45d287fade73a3191ad313ec37231a8c802942/xmonad/xmonad.hs

How can I add/configure keybindings (see the `myKeys` variable) and how can I change from Xmobar to a basic (no config yet) Dzen setup.

It's a setup that doesn't seem to be used in any config I've found and every time eI try to convert it to the other format it doesn't work all that well.

The other format is the `main = do etc. etc. etc.` BTW.

And also, how can I just *convert* from this format to the one that's more commonly used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**About "converting" :**

As xmonad.hs is just haskell source code that is compiled into "your" xmonad, there isn't really a "format" and there are many ways to write the same thing.

If you mean how to convert `main` from using [=<< operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3a-61--60--60-) to *do notation* :

```
main = xmonad =<< statusBar myBar myPP statusbarToggleKey myConfig
```

Here you are using two functions :

- the [statusBar](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html#v%3astatusBar) function that takes four arguments and returns `IO (XConfig (ModifiedLayout AvoidStruts l)`. So basically, using what you passed to it `statusBar` creates the corresponding XConfig and returns it wrapped in the IO monad.
- the [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Main.html) function taking an XConfig and returning IO()

The =<< combines the two : takes the XConfig returned by `statusBar` out of the IO monad and pass it to `xmonad`.

The equivalent in do notation is :

```
main = do 
    config <- statusBar myBar myPP statusbarToggleKey myConfig
    xmonad config
```

But once you understand what the monads operators do, they can look more elegant than do notation.

**Using dzen :**

If you want to keep using the `statusBar` function, you just need to change the arguments you are passing to it.

```
-- the command line to launch the status bar
myBar = "dzen2 -y -1" --that's for dzen at the bottom of the screen
-- the PP
myPP = defaultPP
```

**Key bindings :**

You can see the type of `keys` in [XConfig definition](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Core.html#t%3aXConfig). It's a function taking an XConfig and returning a map.

Here is an example of a "pretty" way to write it, using the `fromList` function from `Data.Map` :

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

myKeys conf@(XConfig {modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
    [
     ((modm, xK_c), kill),
     ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_Return), spawn $ XMonad.terminal conf)
    ]
```

And then if you want to use the keys defined in defaultConfig in addition to yours, you can use `<+>` :

```
myConfig = defaultConfig
    { 
     ...
    , keys = myKeys <+> keys defaultConfig 
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't add the default keys to my custom keys, duh. Works fine for me too.

Answer (score 3):

As for the key bindings, use `additionalKeys` (from the module [XMonad.Util.EZConfig](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-EZConfig.html)).
Here are some key bindings I use (maybe you need some more imports to make everything work):

```
defaultConfig
{
-- stuff
} `additionalKeys`
[ ((0, xK_Print), spawn "scrot")
, ((mod1Mask, xK_Print), spawn "scrot -m -d 1")
, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_t), spawn "killall trayer && trayer --edge top --align right --SetDockType true --SetPartialStrut true  --expand true --transparent true --width 5 --alpha 255 --tint 0x191970 --height 17")
, ((mod1Mask, xK_p), spawn "dmenu_run")
, ((mod1Mask, xK_b   ), sendMessage ToggleStruts)
, ((mod1Mask, xK_m   ), focusUrgent)
, ((mod1Mask, xK_n   ), D.dzen "Hi, mom!" (seconds 4))
, ((mod1Mask, xK_f   ), goToSelected defaultGSConfig)
, ((mod4Mask, xK_l   ), spawn "cmus-remote -n ") --next song
, ((mod4Mask, xK_h   ), spawn "cmus-remote -r") --previous song
, ((mod4Mask, xK_s   ), spawn "cmus-remote -s") --stop
, ((mod4Mask, xK_p   ), spawn "cmus-remote -p") --play
, ((mod4Mask, xK_Right   ), spawn "cmus-remote -k +5") --forward 5 sec
, ((mod4Mask, xK_Left    ), spawn "cmus-remote -k -5") --rewind 5 sec
, ((mod4Mask, xK_KP_Subtract    ), spawn "amixer -q sset PCM 2dB-") --quieter
, ((mod4Mask, xK_KP_Add         ), spawn "amixer -q sset PCM 2dB+") --louder
, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_udiaeresis), removeWorkspace)
, ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_numbersign), selectWorkspace defaultXPConfig)
]
```

The `D.dzen` comes from `import qualified XMonad.Util.Dzen as D`. I don't use dzen as status bar but maybe looking into this module might give you some hints.

edit: here is a dzen config: [And1's_xmonad.hs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive/And1%27s_xmonad.hs). Taken from this site with many examples: [Config_archive](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive).

edit2: I just played around a little with the new `statusBar` function which is apparently quite new and came up with a working example.

edit3: removed the logHook as it isn't needed with `statusBar`. `main` now looks like this:

```
main = do
    xmonad =<< statusBar "dzen2" myPP toggleStrutsKey
    defaultConfig { --stuff
    }
```

The `keys` setting didn't work for me and I had to stick to `additionalKeys` (don't forget the braces then):

```
main = do
    xmonad =<< statusBar "dzen2" myPP toggleStrutsKey
    (defaultConfig { --stuff
    } `additionalKeys`
    [ -- key bindings
    ])
```

Once I tidied my xmonad.hs I can also provide the whole file..

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Will use it in the future probably. :)